# sap.m.Shell: sap icon as homeIcon possible?

Tags: sapui5

My UI5 application uses sap.m.Shell as root control. Can the sap icons be used for property *homeIcon*?
The source text is as follows:

```
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
        sap.ui.require([
            "sap/m/Shell",
            "sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer"
        ], function (Shell, ComponentContainer) {
            new Shell({
                app: new ComponentContainer({
                    height : "100%",
                    name : "<a name>"
                }),
                homeIcon : {
                  'icon': "sap-icon://world",                 
                  'phone' : "sap-icon://world",
                  'phone@2' : "sap-icon://world",
                  'tablet' : "sap-icon://world",
                  'tablet@2' : "sap-icon://world",
                  'favicon' : "sap-icon://world",
                  'precomposed': false
                }               
            }).placeAt("content");
        });
    });
```

Unfortunately the browsers console says:

`GET sap-icon://world net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

UI5 version: 1.42.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not possible. It is using `jQuery.sap.setIcons(oIcons)`. From the API [document](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.setIcons)

> The home icons must be in PNG format...

Also please see another post about [Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674135/where-are-the-sapui5-icons-stored).

Thank you.